# CanoScan FB330P installed on Windows 7 shows as "USB Printing Support"

Tags: windows-7, multi-function-printer

After purchasing an adapter cable for my FB330P Canon scanner I plugged it in to my laptop and Windows installed the drivers but it now shows in Device and Drivers as "USB Printing Support" and when trying to scan I'm told "no scanner connected".

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to install the software for the printer/scanner.  If you are using windows 7/Vista there is great automatic detection of drivers, but NO detection of the software that speaks with the device other than printing.

[Here](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0005946.asp?model=) is the software link for the printer.